# Вызов модального окна при нажатии на строку таблицы

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Как при помощи Bootstrap организовать вызов модального окна при нажатии на строку таблицы? При этом модальное окно будет содержать информацию, которая показана в соответсвующей строке таблицы. Насколько понимаю для этого нужно определять id строки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Независимо, это tr или div... его можно как-то достать через класс, например так:

```js
const bubu = document.getElementsByClassName('bubu');
const modal = document.getElementById('modal');
for(let i = 0; i < bubu.length; i++){
  bubu[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    modal.innerText = this.innerText;
    modal.style.display = 'block';
  });
}

modal.addEventListener('click', function(){
  this.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
#modal {
  display: none; width: 100vw; height: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100500; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  text-align: center;
  }

td { padding: 5px 20px; border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<div id="modal">000</div>

<table>
  <tr class="bubu">
    <td>111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="bubu">
    <td>222</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Код будет меняться, в зависимости - как именно надо заполнять содержимое)